# Google Chrome принудительно использует https

Tags: http, google-chrome, https, протоколы, mamp

Запустил на MacOS MAMP. При обращении через google chrome по адресу http://some.dev браузер автоматически подменяет адрес на https://some.dev. Но с Яндекс.Браузером все нормально. Дело в MAMP или в браузере. Пробовал вот [это решение с хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/95217/), не помогло. Может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google зарегистрировал на себя домен dev (и еще много других gTLD).

> 18(a). Describe the mission/purpose of your proposed gTLD.
>   The proposed gTLD will provide Google with direct association to the term “dev,” which is an abbreviation of the word, “development.” The mission of this gTLD, .dev, is to provide a dedicated domain space in which Google can enact second-level domains specific to its projects in development.

Начиная с Google Chrome 63, .dev включен в список с принудительным HTTP Strict Transport Security.  Поэтому все запросы на него перенаправляются на HTTPS.

Программистам Гугла это удобно, а вам придется использовать другой домен. Например, some.test или same.localhost (https://www.iana.org/assignments/special-use-domain-names/special-use-domain-names.xhtml)

Comment: Где-то тут я уже упоминал, что тот же хром принудительно резолвит localhost в 127.0.0.1 даже если в файле hosts прописано другое, что может создать проблемы с виртуальными сетями в виртуальных машинах

Comment: @andreymal да, мне просто показалось, что топикастеру нужен именно 127.0.0.1. Добавил список спецдоменов на выбор. - прямых ссылок не дам,  т.к. с телефона неудобно :(

Answer (score 1):

Есть странный способ обойти этот запрет. Нужно ввести волшебное слово `badidea` на странице и Хром пустит на сайт.