# Nginx - отключить редирект на 443

Tags: nginx, http-redirect

nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /media/sf_WWW/group.upszn.gov.ua;

    index index.php;

    server_name group.upszn.dev;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    error_log /media/sf_WWW/group.upszn.gov.ua/app/logs/error.log;
}
```

В коде перенаправления на https:// нет.

```
curl -I group.upszn.dev
HTTP/1.1 **200 OK**
...
```

Comment: Домены `.dev` работают **только** на https, такие дела. Меняйте домен, nginx ни при чём

Comment: Спасибо, реально в зоне причина, буду знать :-)

Comment: В таком случае, несмотря на совершенно другую формулировку, получается дубликат вопроса: [Google Chrome принудительно использует https](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779030/google-chrome-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-https)

Comment: Тогда просто удалить вопрос? А то не вижу как его закрыть.

Comment: Не знаю, дубликаты иногда можно не удалять (говорят, помогают с поиском)

Comment: @andreymal, дубликаты **лучше** оставлять: как минимум они содержат другую формулировку вопроса, что может помочь найти нужный ответ.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin однако далеко не любая формулировка поможет на самом деле