# Нежелательный редирект с HTTP на HTTPS для домена

Tags: nginx, http, https, redirect

У одного из популярных регистраторов был приобретен домен, без услуги хостинга, прописана A-запись с IP-адресом машины, на которой развернут веб-сервер Nginx.

Проблема в том, что при попытке обращения к машине по доменному имени происходит замена протокола http на https, даже при попытке напрямую указать перед доменным именем http://

Это точно делает не Nginx, проблема проявляется даже когда Nginx отключен.

Проявляется не во всех браузерах. Например, в Chrome (96.0.4664.110) протокол не подменяется, но в Firefox (96.0) проблема наблюдается стабильно.

Может ли быть проблема в настройках маршрутизатора или firewall'a? Или, возможно, где-то еще?

Comment: Кэш Firefox чистили? На другом компьютере пробовали?

Comment: Да, кэш чистый, в режиме Инкогнито проблема все та же.
На других устройствах проблема тоже наблюдается

Comment: А домен на какие буковки заканчивается (com/org/name/io/dev)?

Comment: Домен на .dev
А это имеет значение?

Comment: Имеет, потому что для абсолютно всех доменов `.dev` включен принудительный HTTPS. И в данном случае очень странно, что в Chrome у вас протокол не подменяется, потому что это изначально как раз гугловская инициатива подменять протокол

Comment: Честно, для меня это стало открытием, спасибо.
Оформите это в виде ответа, пожалуйста, я его приму. Вдруг, кто-то ещё с таким столкнется.

Comment: А оно уже тут было https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779030